# here in this code when i select option A i am getting total = 0 as a output instead of output total = 10, how to solve it?

Tags: python, function, button, tkinter, label

```
total = 0

def round1():
import tkinter
t =tkinter. Tk()
t.title('Round 1')
t.geometry('1000x800')

v1 = tkinter.IntVar()

def marks():
    global total
    if v1.get() == 1:
        total = total + 10
    print("total", total)

l1 = tkinter.Label(t,text = "Q 1 - Is python a case sensitive language?").grid(row = 1)
r1 = tkinter.Radiobutton(t,text = "A - true",variable = v1,value = 1).grid(row = 2)
r2 = tkinter.Radiobutton(t,text = "B - false",variable = v1,value = 2).grid(row = 3)

b = tkinter.Button(t, text = 'Submit',command = marks).place(x = 300, y = 300)
t.mainloop()

def call():
    import tkinter
    t = tkinter.Tk()
    t.title('Instruction')
    t.geometry('1000x800')
    b1 = tkinter.Button(t, text = 'next',command = round1).pack()
    t.mainloop()
call()
```

Comment: Please fix your formatting and indentation

Comment: Have you done any debugging at all? For example, have you verified that `marks` is getting called? Have you verified that `v1.get()` is returning what you think it should? Have you verified that the _type_ of the data returned by `v1.get()` is what you think it is?

Comment: yes, i debug the code there is no error in the code. the v1.get()  return 0 value

Answer (score 1):

This is a well known side effect of using `Tk` more than once. Use `Tk` to create the first window, and use `Toplevel` to make additional windows. It works the same but you don't need a mainloop call.

Also, imports always go on the top, never in a function, and don't initialize and layout a widget on the same line (leads to common bugs).

```
import tkinter

total = 0

def round1():
    t =tkinter.Toplevel()
    t.title('Round 1')
    t.geometry('1000x800')

    v1 = tkinter.IntVar()

    def marks():
        global total
        if v1.get() == 1:
            total = total + 10
        print("total", total)

    l1 = tkinter.Label(t,text = "Q 1 - Is python a case sensitive language?")
    l1.grid(row = 1)
    r1 = tkinter.Radiobutton(t,text = "A - true",variable = v1,value = 1)
    r1.grid(row = 2)
    r2 = tkinter.Radiobutton(t,text = "B - false",variable = v1,value = 2)
    r2.grid(row = 3)

    b = tkinter.Button(t, text = 'Submit',command = marks)
    b.place(x = 300, y = 300)

def call():
    t = tkinter.Tk()
    t.title('Instruction')
    t.geometry('1000x800')
    b1 = tkinter.Button(t, text = 'next',command = round1)
    b1.pack()
    t.mainloop()
call()
```